# How to acces a method from another instance that was given in the constructor?

Tags: c#, oop

So I have the following set-up.

A sensor that detects the temperature of a room a controller then checks if it is below or above a set temperature and if it is below it starts a heater.
Now how do I get the method `GetCurTemp()` to get the temperature I have set?

```
public class TempSensor
{
    public int Temp { get; set; }
}
public class Control
{
    private int threshold;
    public Control(TempSensor t, Heater h, int thr)
    {
      threshold = thr;
    }
    public void SetThreshold(int thr)
    {
        threshold = thr;
    }
    public int GetThreshold()
    {
        return threshold;
    }
    public int GetCurTemp()
    {
        return ???;
    }
}
class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tempSensor = new TempSensor();
        var heater = new Heater();
        var uut = new Control(tempSensor, heater, 25);
        Console.WriteLine("Set the current temperatur");
        int n= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        tempSensor.Temp = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you have a background in Java, as you don't need to make separate `Get` and `Set` methods for properties.

Comment: I (too) am curious why you set up one lonely prop the C# way, and the rest appear to be the Java way.

Comment: Q: Now how do I get ... GetCurTemp()?  A: 1) Declare a new member: `TempSensor tempSensor,];` 2) In your constructor, save a reference to `TempSensor t`, and 3) use the reference ` Control.GetCurrTemp { return tempSendor.GetCurTemp(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the `TempSensor` in your `Control` class. Then you can access the temperature from that reference.

```
public class Control
{
    private int threshold;
    private TempSensor sensor;

    public Control(TempSensor t, Heater h, int thr)
    {
      threshold = thr;
      sensor = t;
    }

    public void SetThreshold(int thr)
    {
        threshold = thr;
    }

    public int GetThreshold()
    {
        return threshold;
    }

    public int GetCurTemp()
    {
        return sensor.Temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with the `TempSensor` object you're passing into the `Control` constructor. You should set up a field like `sensorTemp` in your `Control` class to hold this value.

```
public class Control
{
    private int threshold;
    private int sensorTemp;

    public Control(TempSensor t, Heater h, int thr)
    {
      threshold = thr;
      sensorTemp = t.Temp;
    }

    public void SetThreshold(int thr)
    {
        threshold = thr;
    }

    public int GetThreshold()
    {
        return threshold;
    }

    public int GetCurTemp()
    {

        return sensorTemp;
    }


}
```

Comment: That code is wrong. If he modifies the temp in the TempSensor the change won't propagate (see his example).